# Python quits whenever tkinter is called

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, python-3.6

Using python 3.6 on macOS 10.12 I cannot get any function out of tkinter.

It imports just fine but then calling `Tk()` or `filedialog()` immediately causes this error Window of:

> Python quit unexpectedly

I updated Tcl/Tk from ActiveState and this appeared to have no effect.

I have used tkinter once for a class but I don't have a lot of experience with it, am I simply calling the wrong functions? It seems like any function from the tkinter library causes the same problem.

```
from tkinter import *
Tk()
```

**OR**

```
filedialog.askopenfilename()
```

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: No error message from IDLE, just an os window "Python quit unexpectedly"

Comment: Mac uses their own Tcl/Tk when you update Tcl/Tk on Mac sometimes the python doesn't refer to the newer version and still continue using the pre-installed one. But if you've installed python from python.org (Idle) then there's no use of third-party Tcl/Tk because they're already bundled with 8.6.8 Tcl/Tk and won't refer to any third-party Tcl/Tk. Link for more details: -https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/

Comment: I am fairly certain that I installed from python.org, I will try reinstalling and report back. Thanks

Comment: If that still not help, open the terminal and run `python -m tkinter`  command and let us know the errors if any.

Comment: I downloaded python 3.7 form python.org. This means pip is now still pointing at python3.6, but if I tell it explicitly to look at 3.7 I can reinstall all my modules. The upshot is that tkinter now seems to work. Thanks for the tip

Comment: Ok this is strange: I am now getting the exact same problem as before, but only when I also import pyplot form matplotlib. tkinter and pyplot both work fine, but if I import both, I get the unexpected quit like above. Any idea what that's about?

Comment: Try `pip3 install matplotlib`

Comment: I simply get 'requirement already satisfied' from the terminal, which makes sense because both versions of python on my machine already have the module